# Matching list items to items at the other end of the same list?

Tags: python, awk

I have a list of an arbitrary even number of items.

Input data:

```
Red
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Violet
```

Output data:

```
Red -> Violet
Violet -> Orange
Orange -> Blue
Blue -> Yellow
Yellow -> Green
Green -> Red
```

The idea is that the the highest items are matched with the lowest items, I guess sort of popping things off both ends of a stack.  Once the stack is used up, the last remaining match is whatever we started with.

I started off with this:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {printf("%s -> %s\n",a[i],a[NR-i+1])}}'
```

It matches the top to the bottom, but doesn't "pop".

Is this possible in awk?

Note: I've tagged this "python" because while I don't have any clue how to do this in python, I would very much *like* to know, and will accept a python answer if it's more elegant than an awk answer.  :-)

Comment: what exactly are you inputting and what are you trying to return? In python you would probably want to input a `list` and output a `dict`?

Comment: I'd like to take input from stdin, and send the results to stdout.  I'll want some formatting applied to the output, but as long as I've got a working `printf()`, I should be fine handling that myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Python solution:

```
data = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Violet']
first = data[0]
while data:
    a, b = data[0], data[-1]
    data = data[1:-1]
    print '{} -> {}'.format(a, b)
    print '{} -> {}'.format(b, data[0] if data else first)
```

The starting point here is a list of the data, if you need to read the input from a file you can use the following to populate `data`:

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]
```

If you want to read the data from stdin you can use the following:

```
import sys
data = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]
```

For efficient removal from both the beginning and end of the list, use [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).  Here is how this would look if you are reading from stdin:

```
import sys
import collections

data = collections.deque(line.strip() for line in sys.stdin)
first = data[0]
while data:
    a, b = data.popleft(), data.pop()
    print '{} -> {}'.format(a, b)
    print '{} -> {}'.format(b, data[0] if data else first)
```

Comment: `data = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]`.  No need for `readlines`.

Comment: +1 for a really excellent answer.  My only concern is if the input is large `data[1:-1]` will be inefficient.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski In that case a double-ended queue (collections.deque) would probably address your concerns

Comment: Just edited my answer to include the use of collections.deque.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to step through your input data by twos.

Here's a start in awk, based on your code:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=2;i<=NR;i+=2) {printf("%-10s -> %s\n",a[i/2],a[NR-i/2+1]); printf("%-10s -> %s\n",a[NR-i/2+1],a[i/2+1]);}}' colours
Red        -> Violet
Violet     -> Orange
Orange     -> Blue
Blue       -> Yellow
Yellow     -> Green
Green      -> Green
```

This doesn't handle the "wrap" case in the last line, of course.  To do that, we can expand the code a little.  Here it is, no longer a 1-liner:

```
{a[NR]=$0}

END {
  for (i=2;i<NR;i+=2) {
    printf("%-10s -> %s\n",a[i/2],a[NR-i/2+1]);
    printf("%-10s -> %s\n",a[NR-i/2+1],a[i/2+1]);
  }
  printf("%-10s -> %s\n",a[i/2],a[NR-i/2+1]);
  printf("%-10s -> %s\n",a[NR-i/2+1],a[1]);
}
```

Note the difference in the last option of the final `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

since you prefer an awk solution, try this one:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{
for (i=1;i<=NR;i++){
    t=NR-i+1;
    print a[i]"->"a[t]
    if(t!=i+1)
        print a[t]"->"a[i+1]
    else{
        print a[t]"->"a[1]
        exit;
    }
}
}' file
```

test

```
kent$  cat test.txt
Red
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Violet

kent$  awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{
for (i=1;i<=NR;i++){
        t=NR-i+1;
        print a[i]"->"a[t]
        if(t!=i+1)
                print a[t]"->"a[i+1]
        else{
                print a[t]"->"a[1]
                exit;
        }
}
}' test.txt
Red->Violet
Violet->Orange
Orange->Blue
Blue->Yellow
Yellow->Green
Green->Red
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an awk or a python answer, but you've received plenty of those. Here's one way you could do it with GNU coreutils and sed.

Seeing that the first column is a mix of the top and the bottom of the list, and that the second column is the same, but with the rows rotated up by one, there are a couple of idioms that will be helpful.

Mix lines from top and bottom, but only grab the top half of the list:

```
len=$(wc -l < colours)
paste -d '\n' colours <(tac colours) | head -n $len > colours.mixed
```

Content of `colors.mixed`:

```
Red
Violet
Orange
Blue
Yellow
Green
```

Rotate rows up by one:

```
(tail -n+2 colours.mixed; head -n1 colours.mixed) > colours.mixed.rotated
```

Output:

```
Violet
Orange
Blue
Yellow
Green
Red
```

Taken together this gives the desired result:

```
paste colours.mixed colours.mixed.rotated | sed 's/\t/ -> /'
```

Result:

```
Red -> Violet
Violet -> Orange
Orange -> Blue
Blue -> Yellow
Yellow -> Green
Green -> Red
```

Comment: I like the use of paste and tac, but it can be simplified: `paste colours.txt <(tac colours.txt) | sed 's/\t/ -> /'`

Comment: @glennjackman: that was my first approach, but it doesn't match the output the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Without any IO, but assuming that `colours` is loaded as a list, then a Python solution (although it could do with some tweaking to make it more lazy):

```
colours = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Violet']

from itertools import islice, chain, izip_longest

together = zip(colours, reversed(colours))
flattened = list(islice(chain.from_iterable(together), len(colours)))
for a, b in izip_longest(flattened, flattened[1:], fillvalue=flattened[0]):
    print '{} -> {}'.format(a, b)

Red -> Violet
Violet -> Orange
Orange -> Blue
Blue -> Yellow
Yellow -> Green
Green -> Red
```

And to get `colours`, you could use:

```
import sys
colours = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another python solution.  Note, the value of the term `(i&1)` is the low bit of i, and the value of the term `(i<n-2)` is 1 if i is less than n-2, else is 0.

```
s = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Violet']
n=len(s); j, k = 0, n-1
for i in range(n):
    print s[j], s[k]
    j, k = k, (n-k-(i&1))*(i<n-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused about what you're trying to do since your starting point seems to be a script that produces exactly the desired output you posted!

Clearly I'm missing something but is this what you're looking for instead:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{bos=1; tos=NR; while (bos < tos) {print a[bos] " -> " a[tos]; delete a[tos--]; delete a[bos++] } }'  file
Red -> Violet
Orange -> Blue
Yellow -> Green
```

The difference between my script and yours is that yours will leave "a" intact but when mine's done, if there were initially an even number of elements in "a" then it will be empty, but if there were an odd number then the initial middle element will be all that remains in "a". e.g.:

```
$ cat file                                                                    
Red
Orange
Yellow
Purple
Green
Blue
Violet

$ awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{bos=1; tos=NR; while (bos < tos) {print a[bos] " -> " a[tos]; delete a[tos--]; delete a[bos++] } for (i in a) print a[i] }'  file
Red -> Violet
Orange -> Blue
Yellow -> Green
Purple
```

Comment: Er...  The OP's initial attempt in awk does *not* produce the output he's said he's looking for.  Look more closely.  The idea of using `delete` is interesting, though.

Comment: @ghoti I re-read it and it looks to me like he posted his desired output and a script that produces that output. Did he post output from a script that doesn't work instead of posting the output he actually wants? If so, any idea what output he actually DOES want?

Comment: The script he posted does not produce the desired output.  Try it.  It simply matches top to bottom, rather than alternating output to "connect" the RHS to LHS.  I.e. he wants the second match to be `Violet->Orange`, not `Orange->Blue`.

Comment: @ghoti wow, I looked at the posted output and the script output repeatedly and just could not see the difference. Must be a form of color blindness :-). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!